# Wix upgrade succeeds but new file is missing

Tags: wix, upgrade, wix3

Given two versions of the same wix installer, I am attempting a minor upgrade (same upgrade and product code, version incremented) but having a problem. It includes two features, to each of which I have added one file.

The features look basically like this:

```
<Feature Id="Sample1_Feature" Title="Sample1" Level="1" AllowAdvertise="no" Absent="allow" InstallDefault="local">
  <ComponentGroupRef Id="Sample1ProjectOutput"/>
</Feature>

<Feature Id="Sample2_Feature" Title="Sample2" Level="1" AllowAdvertise="no" Absent="allow" InstallDefault="local">
  <ComponentGroupRef Id="Sample2ProjectOutput"/>
</Feature>
```

In the initial install, all files in the component group get installed with these lines in the log file:

```
MSI (s) (AC:D4) [10:26:58:083]: Feature: Sample1_Feature; Installed: Absent;   Request: Local;   Action: Local
```

and

```
MSI (s) (AC:D4) [10:26:58:083]: Feature: Sample2_Feature; Installed: Absent;   Request: Local;   Action: Local
```

However, during the upgrade the added file for Sample2 is installed but the added file for Sample1 is not. And here is a difference I noticed in the log file:

```
MSI (s) (AC:B8) [10:38:08:682]: Feature: Sample1_Feature; Installed: Advertise;   Request: Reinstall;   Action: Reinstall
```

and

```
MSI (s) (AC:B8) [10:38:08:682]: Feature: Sample2_Feature; Installed: Local;   Request: Reinstall;   Action: Reinstall
```

I believe that the missing file from Sample1 is not installed because the "Installed:" value is Advertise. What I don't understand is why that one is Advertise and Sample2 is (correctly) Local. As you can see above, neither feature allows Advertise.

I would appreciate any help with why this might be happening.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2006/01/23/why-is-my-feature-advertised.aspx) from Heath Stewart. He explains why there might be a situation the similar to what you have. If your problem still can't be narrowed down based on this info, you can nevertheless find the suggestion in the last paragraph useful (about MSIENFORCEUPGRADECOMPONENTRULES property).

Also, [another advice from Heath](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2009/01/27/repairing-products-after-patches-advertised-features.aspx) how to repair products after this accidental advertise has happened. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I needed. I had hoped that I could do a minor upgrade but it turns out we may add and/or remove files between installations. Adding files seems to be okay, but removing certainly isn't.